# Serving for automatic vending machine

Tags: mechanical-engineering, control-engineering, robotics, machine-design

I want a serving mechanism for my vending machine. For my mahine, our product (fried ice cream) will fall into the air fryer and fry it, and then it will come to the plate or bowl to serve. I want to know the idea of a mechanism to bring fried popsicles out of the air fryer and into a bowl.
[image]

This is my first draft, however if you have any suggestions, please describe them in greater detail so that they can be adapt into my draft.

Comment: `fall into the air fryer` ... why would it have to fall in? ... it would make more sense to be inserted by a carrier

Comment: This sounds kind of like a school project. Is it?

Comment: yes it is school project.

Comment: If the cooked item is in free fall, why not put an inclined plane at the bottom and let it *slide* onto the serving tray?

Comment: Yeah but I wanna know what mechanism to remove cooked item from air fryer and slide it into the inclined plane. Such as has rail move the airfryer tray it out or into air fryer and if it come out at the specified point, there is mechanism that opens the bottom of the tray and cooked item will slide into the inclined plane and onto the serving tray.

Comment: Keep it tethered.  If there's a popsicle stick, hang by it.  Have you ever tried playing the claw game?

Comment: Oh sorry i think i use the wrong word, it should be fried ice cream. It look like ball not has stick.